# Changed program a bit, not sure what went wrong

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

So this is just a small form I'm using to send the category name:

```
<form action="insertexp.php" method="post">
Category Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here is my PHP code :

```
$name=$_POST["name"]; 
$dbhost="localhost";
$dbuser="guest";
$dbpsw="";
$dbname="expense";
$conn=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpsw,$dbname);
        if(!$conn)
            die("couldnot open connection");
        echo"connected successfully";
        echo "<br>";

    $sql="INSERT INTO 'itemmaster' ('categoryname')
         VALUES ('$name')";                     


            $val=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            if(!$val)
                die("could not edit table");

            echo ("table edited successfully");

    mysqli_close($conn);
```

I'm sending the form to the correct named page.
The program just won't update my DB, it keeps on dying.

Comment: Wrap off quotes form table and column name instead use backtick

Comment: try to use prepared statement to avoid sql injection

Comment: You can use backtick along table name along with this please write the line $name=$_POST["name"];  after your connection details

Comment: backticks "INSERT INTO `itemmaster` (`categoryname`)
         VALUES ('$name')";

Comment: It's still stuck on could not edit DB. :(

Answer (score 0):

'itemmaster' - this is text not table name. You must use backtick to make it table name. The same with column:

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO `itemmaster` (`categoryname`)
         VALUES ('$name')";
```

Comment: Tried doing it in every way possible, still no solution!

Comment: You can use table and column names without backticks, too.

Comment: So display db error instead of nothing telling *could not edit table*. Use `die( mysqli_error($conn));`

Comment: @nospor Thank you! It says duplicate entry, Somehow my primary key which was set to auto increment stopped working.
Gotta check that now. :)

Comment: But remember, that you also had error with '' = remember to use backticks as I showed you

Answer (score 0):

You have to use backtick in your query:

```
INSERT INTO `itemmaster` (`categoryname`)
     VALUES ('$name')"
```

P.S. Don't put the var directly in your query, because this is vulnerable to sql-injection. Use `mysqli::real_escape_string()` or PDO prepared statment to sanitize your input.
Here PDO documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Try to use mysqli_error as said by nospor, and post the error